# how to use the progressBar.getProgressBar to set color in a xml dynamic?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-progressbar, layer-list

I have a recyclerview and I need to modify the color of a drawable inside OnBindViewHolder, but I can't access the ID of my XML file for that.

I need to access the item with id **circler_center** and set a different color

**My xml**

`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/circle_center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="58dp"
            android:height="58dp"></size>
        <solid android:color="#E2D5D5"></solid>

    </shape>

</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>

    </shape>

</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <solid android:color="#ffff00"></solid>

    </shape>
</item>
```

`

**My onBindViewHolder**

```
´    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Nivels_of_Screen_Middle nivels = list.get(position).get(0);
        MyviewHolder Holder = (MyviewHolder)holder;

        Holder.progressBar.getProgressDrawable()
        .setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        Holder.progressBar.setProgress(nivels.getProgressBar());

        Holder.textView.setText(nivels.getTextView());

        Holder.imageView.setImageResource(nivels.getImageView());
```

}
´

I tried to do the following, used the holder.progressbar.getprogressDrawable (). Setcolorfilter (color.black, porterduff.mode.src_atop);
However, the entire progress bar was painted black and not just the item with the ID circler_center

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

It looks like item with id `circle_center` can have only two states: 1)it is filled with color `E2D5D5` 2)it is filled with `Color.BLACK`. Is this assumption correct? If so, you can create two separate `layer-list` drawables, which will differ by `circle_center` item implementation. And you just swap them dynamically.

**Option 2**

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourLayerListDrawableId);
Drawable circleDrawable = (Drawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.circle_center);
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but in my case it wouldn't be the best choice, because I'm also going to put an image in this XML, which will be defined dynamically, but for that I need to find out how to define the color, so it won't be difficult to find out how set the image.

Comment: @CristianNascimentoMaurício I see, I think there is a better solution for your case, I just updated my answer with 'Option 2'

Comment: Unfortunately, the second option doesn't work either, but I managed to take your first suggestion and adapt it to my case. I took the XML circle and made a new XML for it and in this new one I can set the color using Holder.progressBar.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: @CristianNascimentoMaurício great that it worked out finally